# В VK SDK как отключить постоянную авторизацию?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, android-sdk

```
VKSdk.login(MainActivity.this, VKScope.PHOTOS);
```

Я авторизуюсь в oncreate. После подтверждения вызывается метод который находится в `onActivityResult`.

Но я  видел много приложений где не требовалось каждый раз авторизоваться. Авторизоваться нужно было только 1 раз и в след запуске все работало без авторизации. Подскажите как такое сделать.

У меня в голову приходит только 2 мысли.

> 1) Это в API VK есть уже реализованный способ и нужно где - то, что -
>   то прописать.
>
> 2) Мне вынести функционал запроса из `onActivityResult` допустим в
>   onCreate. И сделать некую проверку на Token. (Хотя мне кажется что 1
>   вариант более действенный, так как вк не маленькая кампания....)

Comment: проверка на токен? он же в преференсах. VK_SDK_TOKEN_PLEASE_DONT_TOUCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед запросом авторизации проверьте авторизован ли уже юзер так:

```
if(!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()){
    //Запускаем авторизацию
}
```

Comment: А если пользователь уже авторизован, то как мне вызвать функцию `VKCallback` которая находится в `onActivityResult`? Чтобы удостовериться что все ок и сделать запрос.

Comment: @EraNewGames, вроде можно настроить какой-то TokenTracker

Comment: Вынесите код оттуда в отдельный метод и вызывайте его если юзер авторизован. Либо вопрос уточнмте- я не вижу в этом проблемы